# get Excel sheet content on a pandas dataframe but with formulas not values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I would like to have a pandas dataframe with the content of an excel file with
the formulas if any.

So from this `test.xlsx` file:

```
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> sheet = load_workbook('test.xlsx', data_only=False).active
>>> for i in range(1, 4, 1):
>>>     for j in range(1, 3, 1):
>>>         print(sheet.cell(i, j).value)
>>>         
4
a
3
b
=A1+A2
=B1&"_"&B2
>>>
```

How can I get this kind of pandas dataframe ?:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
          4              a
0         3              b
1  '=A1+A2'   '=B1&"_"&B2'
```

For now I only get values::

```
In [6]: import pandas as pd
In [7]: df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
In [8]: df 
Out[8]:
   4    a
0  3    b
1  7  a_b
```

Note: I'm on Linux so I can not use `xlwings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openpyxl do this by default and `sheet.values` can be use to construct pandas dataframe:

```
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> sheet = load_workbook('test.xlsx', data_only=False).active
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.values)
>>>
>>> df
0       4           a
1       3           b
2  =A2+A3  =B2&"_"&B3
>>>
```